# jar file for SQLite JDBC connectivity through pyspark and pycharm

Tags: pyspark, pycharm

I am running below code on pycharm , this code is working properly if i provide --jars  through command prompt

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("pySparksqLite_test").\
config('spark.jars.packages', "C:/jars/DataVisualization/sqlite-jdbc-3.20.0.jar").getOrCreate()

spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "5")
df_flight_info =    spark.read.format("jdbc").option(url="jdbc:sqlite:C:/sqlite-tools-win32-x86-3290000/my-sqlite.db",
                                            driver="org.sqlite.JDBC",
                                            dbtable="(select DEST_COUNTRY_NAME,ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME,count from flight_info)")\
.load()
```

but with pycharm i am getting below error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Provided Maven Coordinates must be in the form 'groupId:artifactId:version'. The coordinate provided is: C:/Users/jars/sqlite-jdbc-3.20.0.jar
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitUtils$$anonfun$extractMavenCoordinates$1.apply(SparkSubmit.scala:1000)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitUtils$$anonfun$extractMavenCoordinates$1.apply(SparkSubmit.scala:998)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitUtils$.extractMavenCoordinates(SparkSubmit.scala:998)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitUtils$.resolveMavenCoordinates(SparkSubmit.scala:1220)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.DependencyUtils$.resolveMavenDependencies(DependencyUtils.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:350)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/...../proj1/pySparksqLite.py", line 4, in <module>
    config('spark.jars.packages', "C:/Users/jars/sqlite-jdbc-3.20.0.jar").getOrCreate()
  File "C:\spark\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\session.py", line 173, in getOrCreate
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
  File "C:\spark\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\context.py", line 331, in getOrCreate
    SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
  File "C:\spark\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\context.py", line 115, in __init__
    SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)
  File "C:\spark\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\context.py", line 280, in _ensure_initialized
    SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)
  File "C:\spark\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\java_gateway.py", line 95, in launch_gateway
    raise Exception("Java gateway process exited before sending the driver its port number")
Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending the driver its port number

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have also tried providing jar file path through environment variable and setting it through os

```
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--jars C:/Users/jars/sqlite-jdbc-3.27.2.jar'
```

but even this is not working

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of the `--jars` submitting parameter is `spark.jars` which allows you to specify local jars to transfer them to the cluster. You used `spark.jars.packages` which allows you to download packages from maven by specifying the maven coordinates. The submitting parameter equivalent of that is `--packages`.

Have a look at the documentation for more information: [configuration](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#runtime-environment) and [submitting parameters](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html)